# Resize thumbnail with thimtumb

Tags: php, timthumb

My Word Press Theme Uses

> thimthumb.php

Script for resize thumbnails 
And change the size of images to 190 x 122
How can i change the size of thumbnails to 300*300

Comment: set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 300 ); change it

Comment: I  disabled timthumb . how can do this work without timthumb ?  look at my img tag ->  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/book-190x122.png"